# Lookup.getDefault().lookup() returns null

Tags: java, api, netbeans, lookup, gephi

What should be done if a lookup returns null? I am using Lookup.getDefault().lookup() of `org.openide.util.Lookup` which is used for finding instances of objects. The general pattern is to pass a Class object and get back an instance of that class or null.

I am using it in the code below:

```
StreamingServer server = Lookup.getDefault().lookup(StreamingServer.class);
ServerControllerFactory controllerFactory = Lookup.getDefault().lookup(ServerControllerFactory.class);
StreamingController controller = Lookup.getDefault().lookup(StreamingController.class);
```

Since no istances are found, null is returned for each of these, '`server`', '`controllerFactory`', '`controller`'. I need to handle this situation so I can use these objects to access methods, as in :

```
controllerFactory.createServerController(graph)

server.register(serverController, context)
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I am running my project in Eclipse and have referenced the API's adding the .jar files in the build path.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `META-INF/services` folder in your Eclipse source folder. Then, for each class, create a text file in the `META-INF/services` folder. The name of the text file is the full name (includes the package location) of the class type, and the contents of the text file is the full name (includes the package location) of the implementing class (which is not necessarily the same name of the class).

For example, for the `ServerControllerFactory` class, you will create a text file named `org.gephi.streaming.server.ServerControllerFactory` and the text this file will contain is `org.gephi.streaming.server.impl.ServerControllerFactory`

Answer (score 0):

For me, the class that I was trying to call `lookup` on just needed the `@ServiceProvider` decoration like this:

```
@ServiceProvider(service = MyClassHere.class)
public final class MyClassHere ....
```